# How to read environment variables in properties file for Python client for Kinesis Client Library (KCL)?

Tags: python, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

Is there a way to read the **environment variable** inside the `.properties` file used for the configuration of KCL workers? Specifically, I want to know for ***streamName*** attribute.

Or if it is not possible through the `.properties` file, can I configure KCL **programmatically** somehow? Can I change the stream name or some other configuration inside the Python code while initializing the processor or some other solution?

Comment: is it like using `print(sys.environ, file=file)`?

Comment: The properties file is not a python script, it is a configuration file.

I want to know if there is a solution to set something like  ${stream_name} inside the .properties file.

Or to configure KCL worker programmatically inside python somehow